# Web-based, hosted admin tool for SQL Server database access

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work extensively with MySQL and have no experience with SQL Server. But I have an upcoming project where the existing site's database is on SQL Server. I will be needing to make periodic glances at the existing database, to make SQL dumps most likely so I can write a migration script to the new site database in MySQL. The client will be regularly updating this existing database so just asking for a one-time dump will not help.

Ideally I am looking for a web-based (or desktop based) tool which will allow me to log in to the SQL Server database (I have remote access) and allow me to make a dump or perhaps browse the database structure. Something similar to phpMyAdmin would be nice.

*Update: I should clarify that web-based tools which are ASP based are not ideal. As much as I'd like to learn more about ASP, I do not have the time to set up another environment just to run the tool. Something hosted by a 3rd party would do the trick.*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpeowZXmz3U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also connect via ODBC to your remote MSSQL server then use MSAccess or [OpenOffice to connect](http://www.finefrog.com/2008/04/14/connecting-to-an-mssql-server-and-others-with-openofficeorg/), browse or [backup](http://techierambles.blogspot.com/2009/03/export-to-csv-from-openoffice-base.html).

Comment: This is desktop based, but it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Several options are available (probably quite a few more, too):

- [SQL Web Data Administrator](http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/)
- [SQL Server Web Tools](http://sqlwebtools.codeplex.com/)
- [Article on web based admin tools](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1311)
- [CiberSQL Web Admin](http://www.cibersql.com/csqlwebIDE.aspx)
- [myLittleAdmin (commercial)](http://www.mylittleadmin.com/en/welcome.aspx)
- [SqlWebArchitect](http://www.sqlwebarchitect.org/)
- [MSSQL Web Admin (broken link)](http://ken.blog.leprado.com/scripts-php/mssql-wa/)
- [DBHawk (commercial)](http://www.datasparc.com)