# SQL Server Online browser/editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Could anyone suggest any software which I could deploy on IIS7 and access SQL Server online. I mean browse databases, edit records and etc. It's like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but online version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web-based, hosted admin tool for SQL Server database access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803467/web-based-hosted-admin-tool-for-sql-server-database-access)

Answer (score 2):

[myLittleAdmin](http://www.mylittleadmin.com/en/support.aspx), but it is not free.

myLittleAdmin for MS SQL Server requires the following configuration:

- Microsoft Windows 2000, 2003, 2008
- Microsoft IIS 5, 6,7
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 & 2008
- Microsoft .NET framework 2.0
- A web browser that supports XHTML and CSS2

Comment: @Tomas - have you found what you were looking for?

Comment: No and myLittleAdmin is very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rule on posting a link to another stackoverflow answer is but... here goes:

[Web-based, hosted admin tool for SQL Server database access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803467/web-based-hosted-admin-tool-for-sql-server-database-access)

This one was gaining steam on codeplex but hasn't been updated in awhile.  Last comment was regarding SQL 2005 support.

http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/