# Building web based interface for mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

I am maintaining the databases for my organization in mssql. I have many tables for my database. Now I have to develop a web based service so that any user without the knowledge of sql could access the tables and pull the information they want. I have little knowledge in php...can I build the web based interface in php? Or should I do the web interface using other programming language? Sorry if my question sounds silly..Can anyone please suggest me regarding this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at something like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)?

Comment: http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/ is this something you are looking for?

Comment: @rfausak I have tried phpMyAdmin, but it supports MySQL, and our organization hosts only mssql..Is it an easy task to build a web interface from the scratch to access the mssql? Am I thinking in the right way!!!

Comment: SQL Web Data Administrator **Updated: Nov 14 2007** - Yeesh. Beware.

Comment: @Harri I did not know about this before, Thank you..I will do research about this web based service...Is it applicable to sql server 2008?

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803467/web-based-hosted-admin-tool-for-sql-server-database-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the tables fixed or may there be new ones often?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php

If the tables are fixed you could make pages for each database which will select the data you need and then echo it in a table. You could also build forms and then use that data to do INSERT statements so the users can update the tables

I use MySQL but these manuals will help you to use mssql queries within PHP to select rows in the database and then loop though them echoing the Divs and Tables using $row['column name'] to use the variables.

If the tables could change and you can't find a suitable msSQL equivalent to PHPmyAdmin I would seriously consider changing to MySQL.

Comment: If you need something bespoke then i'd look into PHP mssql queries otherwise look into Harri's answer in the comments.